# Symfony2: dynamically change class property of entity field type

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm working on a project to create marketing campaigns. Among other properties, each Campaign has associated an AudioFile entity which specifies an audio file to be played with that campaign. My form to create a campaign looks like this:

```
 $form = $this->createFormBuilder($CampaignObject)
->add('audiofile', 'entity', array('class'=>'AcmeDemoBundle:AudioFiles', 'property'=>'name',   'multiple'=>false, 'expanded'=>true, 'mapped'=>true))
/*other fields */
```

Apart from that I want to give to the user the possibility to upload a new Audio File "on the fly" while creating a campaign. Once it is uploaded and a new Audio File entity object is created and stored in database I want to dynamically change the entity field to reflect this change in the audio files list, I want to do it without reloading all the page in order not to lose the fields that are already filled but I'm not able to figure out how to achieve that. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Symfony is a back-end framework, which means that to achieve what you want you'll have to implement some Javascript functionality. Also note that the form is stateful and it's instantiated in your controller.

Thus, you'd have to persist your `AudioFile` and then link it to a `Campaign`. That's achievable by having separate forms that accept files and campaigns respectfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I finally found a workaround. I generated the audio list from a getRepository independent of the form an added a select button for each campaign. When user click the select button I fill a hidden field with the id of the Audio File selected. Then when submit in controller I manually get AudioFile object by this id and perform a Doctrine $campaign->addAudiofile($AudioFile) before persist.